# Elixir, how do I rearrange this list?

Tags: elixir

I've got a (long) list of the form:

```
[[X, A], [Y, B]]
```

I want to rearrange it to get:

```
[[X,Y], [A, B]]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `Enum.zip([['x', 'a'], ['y', 'b']]) |> Enum.map(&Tuple.to_list/1)` might work, (`[['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b']]`) _depending_ on what you mean by a long list. For instance: `Enum.zip([['x', 'a', 1], ['y', 'b', 2]]) |> Enum.map(&Tuple.to_list/1)` yields `[['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b'], [1, 2]]`. Also, `Enum.zip()` works differently with atoms.

Comment: And zipping an list like `[['x', 'a'], ['y', 'b'], [1, 2]]` yields `[['x', 'y', 1], ['a', 'b', 2]]`

Comment: Do you mean: Given an input of two lists, produce two new lists with the elements at the same location paired together? Or do you mean: Given a list of 2-element lists, produce a new list of 2-element lists with with the 2nd element of the first pair and 1st element of the second pair swapped? I think it would be clearer if you added a 3rd item to your example lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, if you want to become Elixir professional, this kind of task should be several times made by hands, without any 3rd party or even core library.

Recursion rules.

```rb
defmodule Zip do
  def zip!(input, acc \\ [])
  def zip!([_, []], acc),
    do: Enum.reverse(acc)
  def zip!([[], _], acc),
    do: Enum.reverse(acc)
  def zip!([[h1|t1], [h2|t2]], acc),
    do: zip!([t1, t2], [[h1, h2] | acc])
end

Zip.zip!([[:x, :a], [:y, :b]])
#⇒ [[:x, :y], [:a, :b]]
```

Comment: And then check the core library implementation. :-) The [`Enum.zip/2` implementation](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.1/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L3301) doesn't even use `Enum.reverse/1`.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip your link refers to private reducer implementation.

Comment: Yes, to the actual implementation as called by the public function.

Comment: Public function obviously does `reverse/1`. One cannot recursively reduce adding to head and do not reverse the result.

Comment: It also goes through `Stream.reduce`, but for two lists it is not worth it, hence my implementation is less generic but slightly better for the case of two lists only.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong clause. It doesn't use `Stream.reduce` for lists, it simply uses tail recursion (the function I linked to), which doesn't require reversing the list.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Oh, indeed, correct. There apparently was a glitch in my implementation not handling lists of the different length, fixed, thanks. Going through tuples is not any better than `:lists.reverse/1`, it’s done in Elixir core to have the same outcome as all other `zip`s.

Answer (score 2):

You won't "rearrange" it, since it's immutable.
You can however grab the target parts from the older list with pattern matching.
Then, you can build a new list out of these parts, that will have the shape you want.

```
# Suppose l = [[X, A], [Y, B]]
[[X, A], [Y, B]] = l
l2 = [[X, Y], [A, B]]
```

Then `l2` is precisely what you want.

Demonstration:

```
# Create such a list, with:
#    X = [:a, :b]
#    A = [:c, :d]
#    Y = [:e, :f]
#    B = [:g, :h]
iex(1)> l = [[[:a, :b], [:c, :d]], [[:e, :f], [:g, :h]]]
[[[:a, :b], [:c, :d]], [[:e, :f], [:g, :h]]]

# Through pattern matching, assign the target parts to X, A, Y and B
iex(2)> [[X, A], [Y, B]] = l
[[[:a, :b], [:c, :d]], [[:e, :f], [:g, :h]]]

# Then create a new list from these parts
iex(3)> l2 = [[X, Y], [A, B]]
[[[:a, :b], [:e, :f]], [[:c, :d], [:g, :h]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to [zip](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip/2) your lists:

```elixir
Enum.zip([:a, :b, :c], [1, 2, 3]) |> Enum.map(&Tuple.to_list/1)
```

Output:

```elixir
[[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 3]]
```

The use of [`Tuple.to_list/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Tuple.html#to_list/1) is because `Enum.zip/2` returns a list of tuples, so you need to then convert each tuple to a list.